# Tag wiki excerpts show truncated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tagging

Tag wiki excerpts show up as truncated *from the front* for example in the **Tags** list view (where one can search for specific tag names):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Though all of these tags have correct excerpt texts, starting with capitalized words, e.g. [contexts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contexts):

> Contexts are used in Mathematica to organize defined symbols and avoid
>   conflict between symbols that would otherwise have the same name. They
>   are created when packages are loaded.

None of these tags were edited recently (within 24 hours), so I guess this is not a delayed updating issue.

**EDIT**

Interestingly, none of these are truncated, though they are starting with practically "redundant information":

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just edited the wiki excerpt for [tag:contexts], and it's showing up untruncated for me now.  I'm haven't figured out a pattern yet.

Comment: Looks like they strip away the first few words if it is of the form `<tag name> is|are ...` or `This tag is ...`

This is not unexpected for SE, given that they also strip away "hi", "hello", etc. from posts and @username when addressing post owners, among others.

Comment: I noticed this too.  As RM said, I think it's intentional.  They're trying to strip words that don't communicate much anyway, to fit more into the limited space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, this is intentional. The tag wiki exerpts have extremely limited space to fit in, that's why redundant information at the beginning is removed. See [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @balpha for the explanation. Is there a comprehensive list of what is stripped exactly? Or is that all that is listed at the link you've included? Knowing this could help people to design more concise and informative excerpts.

Comment: Also please see edit in my post.